# Laravel 9 sFTP Unable to write file at location text.txt. not able to write the file

Tags: laravel, sftp

I am trying to create a file on a sFtp server:

`Storage::disk('backup')->put('text.txt', 'My Text');`

Unfortunately, I only get the following error message back, which I can't do anything with:

> League\Flysystem\UnableToWriteFile 
> Unable to write file at location: text.txt. not able to write the file`

I have checked the permissions for the directory, they are ok.

My Filesystem config:

```
'backup' => [
        'driver' => 'sftp',
        'host' => env('SFTP_HOST'),

        // Settings for basic authentication...
        'username' => env('SFTP_USERNAME'),
        'password' => env('SFTP_PASSWORD'),

        'throw' => true,
    ],
```

Comment: Please add your filesystem config.

Comment: Can you read files from that disk or do you have similar errors?

Comment: @Ralla: Here my filesystem config: `'backup' => [
            'driver' => 'sftp',
            'host' => env('SFTP_HOST'),

            // Settings for basic authentication...
            'username' => env('SFTP_USERNAME'),
            'password' => env('SFTP_PASSWORD'),

            'throw' => true,
        ],`

Comment: @apokryfos: Reading data unfortunately also does not work, unfortunately no error message comes.

Comment: double check that the permissions work for the sftp user. Try some normal sftp client software to see if that works with your credentials